# how to send csrf token through ajax call in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, token, csrf, mismatch

i have a form with method=post.In that form i have an image upload field which is ajax.when the ajax call process,verify csrf token mismatch error occure.help me.this is my code..,

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on("click", "#upload", function() {
                    var file_data = $("#groupe_img").prop("files")[0];   // Getting the properties of file from file field
                    var form_data = new FormData();                  // Creating object of FormData class
                    form_data.append("file", file_data)              // Appending parameter named file with properties of file_field to form_data
                    form_data.append("csrftoken",document.mainform.csrftoken.value;)                 // Adding extra parameters to form_data
                    $.ajax({
                                url: "/upload_avatar",
                                dataType: 'script',
                                cache: false,
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                data: form_data,                         // Setting the data attribute of ajax with file_data
                                type: 'post'
                       })
                })
            });
        </script>
```

this is my html portion

```
<input type="file" name="groupe_img" id="groupe_img">
<button id="upload" value="Upload">upload image</button>
```

tysm

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684928/how-to-automatically-add-x-csrf-token-with-jquery-ajax-request-in-laravel

Answer (score 4):

First add `csrf` token to a meta tag like this (*in main layout for example: resources/views/default.blade.php  in head section*):

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

Then use `$.ajaxSetup` before ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: "/upload_avatar",
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'post'
})
```

Comment: where should i place this code..? didnt get it clearly..help

Comment: Add meta tag in the default layout (in resources/views folder), and ajaxSetup before ajax call. I edited my answer, check it.